# Drastically different performance on similar computers

Tags: windows-10

I recently had to convert a pretty big batch (30GB) of videos from one format to another, and I figured I'd split up the work amongst my desktop and laptop. Despite having similar specs, my laptop finished the jobs SIGNIFICANTLY faster (6-10x as fast). I looked into it a bit as the jobs were running, and was surprised to see that on my laptop, CPU usage was hovering around 80-90%, mostly by the one process. On my desktop, however, CPU usage was only around 10-15%, even though I had nothing else running. Furthermore, the desktop seems almost frozen while running the jobs, running a web browser is incredibly slow, but I can do plenty of other things on my laptop without any performance issues. I'm wondering why my desktop's operating system seems to be limiting this process's resources and potentially how to remedy it. I just took an intro class in operating systems so I should still understand a pretty technical explanation.

Here are the specs:

Desktop: 4-core i5 @2.5GHz, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, Win 10 Education

Laptop: 2-core i7 @2.4GHz, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, Win 10 Home

Both machines have integrated graphics, if that matters

Thanks!

Comment: Can you list the exact CPU models, rather than just i5 and i7? I also assume you have your core counts backwards. i5 would be dual core and the i7 would be the quad core.

Comment: I can't quite explain the differences in CPU usage, but I can point out a few obvious things regarding the speed. The i5 is a dual core and probably does not support hyper threading. The i7 is a quad core and probably supports hyper threading. Having the extra cores and hyper threading could give you a pretty good boost in performance.

Comment: Actually the cores are correct (i5 has 4, i7 has 2), it's because the i7 is a mobile version (i7-4500U) in my laptop.  The desktop has an i5-2400s.

Comment: But you are correct that the i5 does not have hyper-threading

Comment: Well, then my comment isn't very relevant. The CPU usage definitely seems to be the big factor. If it's only running 10-15% of it's maximum speed, then the laptop will be faster all the time.

Comment: You should mention the application and/or flags used (ffmpeg etc) to convert. Discussions about cores are not really worthwhile if the application is set up for single-threaded operation. In that case, the i7 is probably going to win. Also, the desktop may be using the GPU for GPU accelerated rendering, (assuming support in hardware and software), but this may actually be a performance hit (?)

Answer (score -1):

The numbers may be the same, but usage and generations may be drastically different.

Your laptop uses an i7 which supports hyperthreading, which basically allows for multitasking. The process most likely detected a large number of logical cores and dispatched multiple processing threads but left one of the logical cores unused for other processes to use, which prevents freezing. Thus, the CPU was used effectively.

Let's look at your desktop. An i5 is not likely to have hyperthreading, so each core is a physical core. Since the software did not detect a large amount of cores, it probably just left the jobs single-threaded, which means that all the jobs only ran on one core.

Comment: Both systems have the same number of logical cores, though (i7 has 2*2(hyperthreading)=4, while the i5 has 4 physical cores)